# Laravel cookie sent to browser but not saving it

Tags: php, cookies, laravel-5

I am working with Laravel 5.2. When I am working on my local environment (vagrant) the code works and the cookies are being saved at the browser. but when I try it on production environment, the cookie is sent to the browser but it's not saved. Can anyone help me please?

It's look like a CROS problem.

headers:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type');
```

Larvel code:

```
if (isset($cookies['poptin_display'])){
    //var_dump($cookies);
    return response()->json($poptinTrigger)->withCookie('poptin_dispaly_returning_visitor',$visit_counter, 86400)->withCookie('poptin_dispaly_after_x_visiting',$visit_first_time, 86400);
}else{
    return response()->json($poptinTrigger)->withCookie('poptin_display',true, 1440)->withCookie('poptin_dispaly_returning_visitor',$visit_counter, 86400)->withCookie('poptin_dispaly_after_x_visiting',$visit_first_time, 86400);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well the lifetime is only 1440 seconds which will be 24 mintues . try increasing it  to at least a day

Comment: It's doesnt' matter! The other two are much more longer. thank for your help!